# If p ⇒ q and q ⇔ r how can I prove p ⇒ r at Fitch?

Tags: logic

Good afternoon.

There was a small problem - I can not prove this expression using Fitch.

Prove [image: Prove.]

Alas, when trying to prove it on the 10th line, he indicates that the solution is not correct, although I came to the answer that was necessary for the task.
Perhaps my reasoning is somewhat erroneous.
Thank you in advance for your help.

**UPD.** Thanks, I find the solution.

Correct proof [image: Correct prove.]

Comment: It appears that you are using some sort of electronic system to verify your work.  Check that you have your attempt written in the correct format with correct nesting.  If I were to prove this myself on paper, I wouldn't go any further than saying "since $p\implies q$ and $q\implies r$ and since implication is transitive, it follows that $p\implies r$"

Comment: @JMoravitz: Note that the Fitch system is using Natural Deduction, and while it's certainly true that implication is transitive, that's not an allowed inference rule in Natural Deduction. You have to use only Introduction and Elimination rules for each symbol.

Comment: Basically, it is a duplicate of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411267/i-have-to-give-a-fitch-proof-without-any-premises-only-for-fitch-system).

Comment: @JMoravitz  It is the [Standford Logica's Fitch System](http://logica.stanford.edu/logica/homepage/fitch.php) to be precise, which uses a version of Fitch's Natural Deduction that doesn't include the falsum constant ($\bot$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're kind of making it unnecessarily complex. Try this:
\begin{align*}
1.\quad p\to q\quad &\text{premise} \\
2. \quad p\leftrightarrow q \quad &\text{premise} \\
3. \quad q\to r\quad&\text{Biconditional elimination} \\
4. \qquad |p \quad &\text{assumption}\\
5. \qquad |q \quad &\text{Implication elimination 1, 4}\\
6. \qquad |r \quad &\text{Implication elimination 3, 5}\\
7. \quad p\to r \quad &\text{Implication introduction 4-6}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, I update post, that one's correct.

Answer (score 0):

In line 5, you assume $q$.  Conditional on that, you show $p \implies r$.  So what you have shown is $q \implies (p \implies r)$.  (The running set of assumptions is what is being tracked by the vertical lines between the row numbers and your expressions.)

I haven't used Fitch.  Can you also show $\lnot q$ implies $p \implies r$?  Then combine these to eliminate conditioning on $q$?  (Or use the more direct methods explained in other answers...)